# Incidence angle in pulsed laser deposition (PLD)

Tags: experimental-physics, laser

Why is an incidence angle of 45° the best choice in pulsed laser deposition (PLD)?
Why not 20 or 30 degrees, if reflection is effect or not?

Comment: paging @JonCuster at the white courtesy telephone....

Comment: (1) The plume from the laser-heated region is ~normal to the surface. You want it to hit your sample, not your optics. Yet perpendicular incidence on the target would be the best spot size and shape. (2) The more parallel to the substrate, the larger your laser spot on the target is, reducing the effectiveness  of the laser heating, reducing the dep rate. The rest is tradeoffs...